# Is there an alternative to the xinput --query-state command that works on wayland instead of only X11?

Tags: x11, wayland, xinput

To put it most simply: I need to be able to check if any key is in the down or up state at any time from a script.

To explain my use case:

I have a have a script thats meant to execute while a certain key (f14 in this case) is already being pressed down. It loops indefinitely until that key is released. It does by using the xinput --list and --query-state commands to check the status of the key, and making a loop that will continue as long as the key is in the "down" positition. The script will check the status of the key on each loop, and if the key is released, the script terminates.

This script worked great on X11. The issue is that X11 hates both my computer and my monitor configuration, so I've had to switch to Wayland for usability's sake. Now I'm struggling to find a replacement for xinput. It's not important if I can tell the difference between key presses on different keyboards like xinput can, I just need some way to be able to detect whether a key is "down" or "up".

I have the script working again, but only thanks to the fact that KDE Plasma on Wayland lets you allow X11 apps specifically to read all keyboard inputs at all times like they're able to on X11. The problem I have with this is that I would prefer to have a native wayland solution rather than a hacky workaround that could be removed or stop working at some point (ignoring possible security vulnerabilities). I've found some programs like evscript that claim to work, but I have no idea if they actually would work for this specific purpose or not.

TL;DR: I need a script to terminate when a key is released. How do I do that without xinput?